# Definition of inductive predicate in first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic, foundations

Given a foundation of first order logic how would you define inductive predicates like testing if a natural number is even?

From my background in type theory I am aware you can compile down pattern matching with recursion to use of induction principles (possibly also with axiom K.) So I think as an example for Peano arithmetic you would compile down inductive predicates to use of a recursor predicate axiomized as something like

$$\mu(P, \phi. Q, \text{O}) \iff P$$
$$\mu(P, \phi. Q, \text{S}(x)) \iff [\phi := \mu(P, \phi. Q, x)]Q$$

But this seems like a very constructive approach. Are there better or cleaner ways to do this sort of thing perhaps with classical first order logic?

I am also aware of impredicative encodings but those require higher order logic.

Comment: You actually don’t even need to axiomatise recursive functions in Peano arithmetic. All primitive recursive functions are definable in Peano arithmetic, including Kleene’s T predicate. This allows a direct encoding of recursive functions.

Comment: @MarkSaving https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52141/239001 Huh so I read up on this and I think T's predicate only lets you define computable predicates. I don't know what to think about undecidable predicates.

Comment: The $T$ predicate allows you to define any semi-decidable predicate, including some undecidable ones. Essentially, $T(n, m, k)$ means, to a rough approximation “the $n$th recursive function, applied to input $m$, halts in $k$ steps”. So you can discuss recursive functions that aren’t total.

Comment: @MolossusSpondee In fact, using the $T$ predicate + quantification you can define any function computable from ${\bf 0}^{(n)}$ (the "$n$th halting problem") for any finite $n$. And this is optimal: any function definable over $\mathbb{N}$ using addition and multiplication is computable from ${\bf 0}^{(n)}$ for some finite $n$. This is basically the content of [Post's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_theorem).

Comment: @NoahSchweber so I don't really see how this is different from defining a predicate $\text{eval}$ evaluating a formula with n free variables on n arguments. Which I think might work for some stuff but is very confusing and I'm not sure of it's limitations.